# Ajax not functioning to post data to PHP to delete SQL row

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I want my users to be able to delete a listing using an html from that starts an ajax funtionc to post the data to a php script. I would also like to add a confirmation message before the script is run...something like "are you sure you want to delete this listing. I've been at this all day I can't get it to work. If you notice anything wrong...

HTML Secured Page with form and Ajax

```
require_once ('verify.php'); 
$page_title = 'delete_listings.php';
 ob_start();
session_start();

Ajax

<head>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function () {
      $('form_del').bind('click', function (event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                   url: 'delete_list.php',
                 data: $('form_del').serialize(),
              success: function () {
           alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
```

PHP output and form

```
<body>
<?php
    include ("dbconlisting.php");
    $query="SELECT * FROM listings";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<?php while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
        $id = $data['id'];
        $listing_img = $data['listing_img'];

    ?>

<img src="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" width="150" />

 <form name="form_del" id="form_del">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <br>
  <input name="submit" class="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
        <?php endwhile;mysqli_close($con);?>
 </body>
 </html>
<?php
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

delete_list.php

```
<?php
include 'dbconlisting.php';
if($_POST) {
$del_id=$_POST['id'];
$delete = "DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = $del_id";
$result = mysqli_query($delete) or die(mysqli_error());
} else{ echo 'error' ;}
?>
```

Comment: Which part is not working? Like where does it break down?

Comment: Or is it just that you don't know how to incorporate this warning message?

Comment: @Rasclatt button clicks, page blinks (I'm guessing it goes to the php script) and original page remains. Item still there - item doesn't get deled. I know the php mechanics on the page with the form are working.

Comment: @Rasclatt I can do the warning message actually, i'm really in need of getting the communication working and the sql item deleted.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"> and in javascript function use instead of document.getElementByTagName("id").value, use this document.getElementById("id").value

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do for your ajax portion in your head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Delete button -> confirmation
    function DeleteId(ElemVal) {
        $('#'+ElemVal).submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_list.php",
                    data: $('#'+ElemVal).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        //  alert('form was submitted');
                        }
                });

            return false;
            });
        }

// Confirmation -> Delete
function RemoveId(ID) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_list.php",
            data: { deleteId: ID },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                    $('#form_del'+ID+"_wrap").html(data);
                //  alert('form was submitted');
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

For your html loop:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id             =   $data['id'];
        $listing_img    =   $data['listing_img']; ?>

<div id="form_del<?php echo $id; ?>_wrap">
    <img src="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" width="50" />
    <form name="form_del" id="form_del<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br />
        <input name="submit" class="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" onClick="DeleteId('form_del<?php echo $id; ?>')">
    </form>
    <div id="form_del<?php echo $id; ?>_confirm"></div>
</div><?php
    }; ?>
<div id="response"></div>
```

**delete_list.php**

```
<style>
.delete_button { cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: red; border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block; color: #FFF; }
</style>
<?php
    // If confirm submits action to delete
    if(isset($_POST['deleteId'])) {
        include('dbconlisting.php');
        // Run the mysql delete function
        $del_id    =   $_POST['id'];
        $delete    =   "DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = $del_id";
        $result    =   mysqli_query($delete) or die(mysqli_error()); ?>

        <p>DELETED.</p>
<?php }
    // If action to confirm is submitted
    elseif(isset($_POST['id'])) { ?>
    <div class="delete_button" onClick="RemoveId('<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>')">Are you sure?</div><?php
        }
    // default
    else { ?>
    <h3>Invalid ID</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I edit's my question with your suggestions, but no change in function

Comment: is that hidden input messing this up? should it be in the id of the button?

Comment: i included the bufferring and session functions because i didn't know if it could be messing this up. It shouldn't though ajax is only client side I thought

Comment: Ok here is a solution that will work on your forms. I tried this and it works. You can see the ajax happen in the `<div id="response"></div>`.

Comment: made changes, button seems dead. I will need to pick this up in the am. I really don't like ajax, it's just unfortunately very useful. Thank you for all your help with this sincerely, I will check this question in the am

Comment: Here is a working demo. When you click the delete button, it fires the ajax and submits the id to the delete page (mine just displays the id though, yours would do it's confirm thing and delete): [demo](http://www.xolifestyleworldwide.com/client_assets/workboard.php)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
function postData(){
       if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?"))
       {
         var value = document.getElementByTagName("id").value;
         $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          data:"&id="+value,
          url: "delete_list.php",
          success: function(){
             alert("Submited Successfully!");
          }
        });
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
```

}

Comment: syntax errors line 8 and last line, i'm including that close bracket off the coding screen. I fixed syntax, when user clicks button page goes into a loading state then stops, nothing happened

Comment: put comma after "delete_list.php" please

Comment: is prob with my hidden input?

Comment: First alert the value

Comment: If you alert the value its correct it means no problem with hidden field

Comment: no error or any messages come up. the page loads and stops. if i refresh the item isn't deleted.if i log out and log back in, still not deleted.

Comment: No import form method